# Deploying Django with Apache

Tags: django, apache, apache2, deploying

I already have a Django web application working, and I wanted to make it visible through Internet. I would even consider using Django alone, since it is only a prototype I want to show to someone, and security is not a priority for me right now. But since this looks impossible to achieve (or at least I haven't been able to do it), I'm moving to Apache.

The problem is that there are many tutorials, and each one do different things.

Until now I have:
- Installed apache (and works)
- Installed mod_wsgi (and module is loaded into Apache)
- Since my Django web app is in /home/myuser/www/myapp/ (or at least that's where I'm storing the manage.py file, the rest of the application is in /home/myuser/www/myapp/myapp/), I tried to make apache point there. So I created (home/myuser/www/myapp/apache.conf/web.wsgi with the following content:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/www/myapp/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

BTW I also have the wsgi Django automatically generates when creating a new project in /home/myuser/www/myapp/myapp/wsgi.py. Maybe I should use this one, but none of the tutorials I have found until now do mention this file. Any way, its content is:

```
import os
# We defer to a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE already in the environment. This breaks
# if running multiple sites in the same mod_wsgi process. To fix this, use
# mod_wsgi daemon mode with each site in its own daemon process, or use
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myapp.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from myapp.wsgi import MyAppApplication
# application = MyAppApplication(application)
```

Finally, I created the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp, using the default one as a template, and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/myuser/www/myapp/

    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AddHandler mod_python .py
        PythonHandler mod_python.publisher | .py
        PythonDebug On
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/myuser/www/myapp/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/myuser/www/myapp/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /home/myuser/www/myapp/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Despite my efforts described, when I navigate to localhost I just see the default apache web, saying 'It works!'.

Any help please? What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you enable your "myapp" site in Apache ?

```
a2ensite myapp
```

Because apparently you just created the config file in "sites-available/", that's not enough ;)

**EDIT** : you probably want to disable the default site, before typing the above command :

```
a2dissite default
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the default site enabled. Remove /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default (or something like that, can't remember ATM, but something with default) and restart apache.